# SHAP: dependence_plot doesn't work with an error which is related deep inside the function

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, shap, xai

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import shap
import xgboost 

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",")
labels=df.pop('target')

model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(df, labels)

# compute SHAP values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df)

df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
shap.dependence_plot(1, shap_values, df)
```

and my data is:

```
Cat1,Cat2,Age,Cat3,Cat4,target
0,0,18,1,0,1
0,0,17,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,1,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,0,17,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,0,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,17,1,0,0
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,1,16,1,1,1
0,0,15,0,0,1
0,0,16,1,0,1
0,1,15,1,0,1
```

when I run this code, I am getting this error:

```
Passing parameters norm and vmin/vmax simultaneously is not supported. Please pass vmin/vmax directly to the norm when creating it.
```

The error is deep inside of this function and I am not sure how my data can change it.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading **matplotlib** to **3.2.2** or explicitly set the interaction_index works for me.